# planar graphs with minimum degree 4

Tags: topological-graph-theory

Is it true:

there is a simple planar graph $G$ with

- minimum degree $4$,
- each $2$ vertices of degree $4$ are nonadjacent
- $G$ has no vertices of degree $5$.

Comment: Does your graph need to be simple? If not, then it is pretty easy to construct such a graph.

Comment: $G$ is a simple graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

There are infinitely many such graphs. Have fun ;-)

Comment: Thank you  for the answer.I'm grateful for the help